# How to prevent "Incorrect block count for file" file system errors from occurring?

Tags: hard-drive

On our 10.7 Lion installation, 3 out of 9 drives are repeatedly suffering from

> Incorrect block count for file

errors when running a `diskutil repairVolume` command.

---

- The drives are having capacities of 3TB and 4TB.
- The drives are attached via a SATA bus.
- There is no relation between drive capacity and these errors occurring.
- A 4TB drive is listing roughly 5000 file and 1500 folder entries.
- Of these 5000 files, 3000 files are more than 64K in size.
- 4 Out of 5 of the 3TB drives are not experiencing these "**Incorrect block count for file**" issues.
- The drives are encapsulated in silicon jackets to reduce vibrations.
- The faulty drives also have IO issues in application software, resulting in write() errors.
- Each 3TB drive with 512 byte sectors is partitioned and formatted with commands similar (*replace disk number and Volume name*) to these:

---

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
sudo gpt destroy /dev/disk2
sudo gpt -p 1 create -f /dev/disk2
sudo gpt label -i 1 -l E disk2
sudo gpt add -t hfs /dev/disk2
sudo newfs_hfs -b 65536 -c a=1,c=8,e=1 -n e=1024,c=4096,a=4096 -v E /dev/disk2s1
diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2
cd /Volumes/E
sudo rm -fr .{,_.}{fseventsd,Spotlight-V100,Trashes}
mkdir .fseventsd
touch .fseventsd/no_log .Trashes
sudo touch .metadata_never_index .com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent
sudo mdutil -dE -i off /Volumes/E
sudo tmutil addexclusion /Volumes/E
```

## Update #1

- When ( 33% of the data {1.3TB of free space} is moved to a different drive OR 5 drives were unmounted by the system and manually re-mounted), 1 of the drives does no longer have issues, and the other faulty drive does still have write() issues.

## Question

What can be done to prevent these "**Incorrect block count for file**" errors from happening in the first place?